# Modificar estructura de carpetas React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, programación-móvil

Mi pregunta es muy simple, quiero modificar la estructura de carpetas de mi  proyecto de React Native a la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta es:

- Independientemente de la estructura de mi proyecto, ¿tengo que importar todas mis clases y funciones a **App.js** o **Index.js**  para que funcione?

Por que por lo que tengo entendido se llama a **App.js** o **Index.js** a la hora de ejecutar el proyecto.

Answer (score 0):

Efectivamente deberás importar tus funciones en App.js o Index.js del siguiente modo:

```
// Funciones de React y React Native que vayas a utilizar, por ejemplo

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Text, StyleSheet, View, FlatList, TouchableHighlight, Keyboard } from 'react-native';


// Tus funciones leídas desde la estructura que hayas elegido para tu Proyecto, por ejemplo:

import MisFunciones from './componentes/MisFunciones';
import FormularioA from './componentes/FormularioA';
```